# Font Book reports "serious problems" with Code 2000?

Tags: font, font-book, macos

I just downloaded [Code 2000](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code2000) from Wayback Machine but when I tried to install it Font Book reported a serious error but no further details.

Anyone know what might be the problem? Are there any online resources that allows me to verify a font's integrity and hopefully could give me some more details about any potential issues?

Comment: It doesn't look like James Cass fully completed the [Code 2000 project](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code2000) at all.

Comment: @IconDaemon It was very advanced for its time, but Unicode coverage has grown tremendously and there are now many other fonts available to handle it, including https://www.google.com/get/noto/

Comment: @TomGewecke Newer alternatives such as? I like a font that my computer can fall back on when it's missing certain unicode characters.

Comment: @d-b do you have an example of something missing?  Macos probably already covers more than the very old  Code 2000.  Did you not see the link i gave for Noto fonts?

Comment: Futhark? @TomGewecke

Comment: @d-b  According to Character Viewer my MacOS 10.11 covers the Runic range (U+16a0 onward) with both Geneva and Apple Symbols without any extra fonts needed.

Comment: You might want to try Everson Mono font which has nearly as many nonCJK glyphs in its repertoire as Code2000.

Answer (score 1):

In my experience Font Book warnings rarely have any real consequences.

It's also hard to imagine any issues that could not be easily fixed by just removing the font.  Install it manually in Home/Library/Fonts and see if you find any problems.

To get to Home/Library, hold down the option key while doing Finder > Go.

If your goal is to ensure complete Unicode coverage, I suspect MacOS already has more of this than the very old Code 2000.  To expand coverage beyond what Apple offers, I would recommend the [Google Noto fonts](https://www.google.com/get/noto/) and [Symbola](http://users.teilar.gr/~g1951d/).

To see what font has a specific character when Apple's Character Viewer is empty, try [Fileformat](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/search.htm).